# Can I remove the "Side panel" button from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to remove the side panel button from Chrome?

[image: reading_list_button_arrow]

The suggestions [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+remove+reading+list+button) don't work, and according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/uwyr99/chrome_102_how_do_i_remove_the_side_panel_button/) it's not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: @John say whay? Your comment makes absolutely NO SENSE!